# Accessing enum values in struct with if statement

Tags: swift, if-statement, struct, enums

Having struct like this:

```
struct ScrollTableViewColumn {
    var ContentType: ContentType

    enum ContentType {
        case String
        case Numeric(sum: Double, width: CGFloat)
    }
}
```

I can access the numbers stored in content type with *switch statement* like this:

```
switch column.ContentType {
case .Numeric(let sum, let width):
   // do something with sum and width…
```

How can I achieve similar thing with *if statement*?

Comment: `if case .Numeric(let sum, let width) = column.ContentType {`

Comment: You should start property names and enum values with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @NiravD Oh, I was close! Thank you, maybe use this to answer the question and I can accept it?

Comment: @vacawama you're right, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to make property names and enum values with a lowercase, so change your `enum` like this.

```
enum ContentType {
    case string
    case numeric(sum: Double, width: CGFloat)
}
```

Now you can use `if case` this way.

```
if case .numeric(let sum, let width) = column.ContentType {
     print(sum, width)
}
```

**Edit:** You can also make `if case` like this way.

```
if case let .numeric(sum, width) = column.ContentType {
     print(sum, width)
}
```

Comment: You need to fix .Numeric and you might as well make .ContentType lowercase as well.